# Connection of Android Studio project to MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio

I am developing an android studio project and would like to be able to access data from a database sitting on the pc which I am programming from. I would like to use a MySQL database as I have worked with them before. I was wondering if it is possible to do it from android studio. If it is possible what would the code be for me to do it? I have looked through other people's questions and answers and all of them yield errors for me.
Thanks in advance

I have tried the following and all my ip, port, username and password information is correct but I keep getting the following error: **E/Error in connection: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**
My code in my connection class after declaring my attributes is as follows

```
        //declaring connection policy
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection connection = null;
        String ConnectionURL = null;

        //starts actual connection to db
        try
        {
            //establishing connection to Database
            //all hard coded
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            ConnectionURL= "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+ ip + ":"+ port+";"+ "databasename="+ database+";user="+uname+";password="+pass+";";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
        }
        //Catches any error in the data
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //executes if there is a error connecting to the database
            Log.e("Error in connection", e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Error connecting to db");
        }
        //returns the connection to the main class
        //it will then be sent to the DBmanager class and used to get the data out of the database
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Comment: a direct connection of apps to a mysql server(and for other rdms also) is discouraged, as you need for this open your database to the internet with a direct access, which is a fatal security risk. take a look at REST API Mmsql android and you will find a lot of tutorials

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will take a look. Can you publish this as an official answer and I'll accept it as a official answer because It is really useful as I have found it hard to find a good answer

Comment: I'm ok with that: A direct connection is a security risk. But what if I want to manage my casual project like this before publishing or scaling it? I don't think it is a solution for the answer if I just want to test and (important) avoid PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a direct connection of apps to a mysql server(and for other rdms also) is discouraged, as you need for this to open your database to the internet with a direct access, which is a fatal security risk.

search for

- REST API MySQL android

and you will find a lot of tutorials

like this short one https://phppot.com/php/php-mysql-rest-api-for-android/ or this https://www.javahelps.com/2018/12/access-mysql-from-android-through.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this require a good knowledge of php or is it relatively easy to figure out?

Comment: there are a lot of turials for that as well, but both  showed you, show you how to start, the rest you will have to learn, but when you have some experience in programming like c or c# java, pho is easy to learn

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio will struggle with connecting to a mySQL database. It is often easier to store a sqlite db on the machine itself for this use case.

Comment: Yes, tried, but the problem is, my friend, that we can not put it online.